# Nested collections in forms

Tags: php, forms, symfony, collections

I tried to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29699043/6105710) answer to handle nested collections in forms.

I have an `Application`'s Form with a collection of `LienAppliServ`'s Form :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('servLiens', 'collection', array(
            'label' => ' ',
            'type' => new LienAppliServType(),
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'by_reference' =>false,
            'prototype' => true,
        ))
    //...
```

In my `LienAppliServ`'s Form, I have another collection of `PortLienAppliServ`'s Form :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('ports', 'collection', array(
            'type' => new PortLienAppliServType(),
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'prototype' => true,
            'by_reference' =>false
        ))
    //...
```

And the form of PortLienAppliServ is :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('numPort')
        ->add('type')
    ;
}
```

Now, I'd like to handle add/delete for each collection...
As I said, I tried to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29699043/6105710) answer

In order to do that, I tried :

```
{% block body -%}
    {{ form_start(form) }}

            <ul id="col-servliens" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.servLiens.vars.prototype)|e }}">
                {# iterate over each existing tag and render its only field: name #}
                {% for servLiens in form.servLiens %}
                    <li>{{ form_row(servLiens) }} </li>
                    <ul id="col-ports" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(ports.vars.prototype)|e }}">
                    {%for ports in servLiens.ports %}
                        <li>{{ form_row(ports) }}</li>
                    {% endfor %}

                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {{ form_end(form) }}

{% endblock %}

{% block app_js %}

    //Same as the other question
    <script>
        function FormCollection(div_id)
        {
            // keep reference to self in all child functions
            var self=this;

            self.construct = function () {
                // set some shortcuts
                self.div = $('#'+div_id);
                self.div.data('index', self.div.find(':input').length);

                // add delete link to existing children
                self.div.children().each(function() {
                    self.addDeleteLink($(this));
                });

                // add click event to the Add new button
                self.div.next().on('click', function(e) {
                    // prevent the link from creating a "#" on the URL
                    e.preventDefault();

                    // add a new tag form (see next code block)
                    self.addNew();
                });
            };

            /**
             * onClick event handler -- adds a new input
             */
            self.addNew = function () {
                // Get the data-prototype explained earlier
                var prototype = self.div.data('prototype');

                // get the new index
                var index = self.div.data('index');

                // Replace '__name__' in the prototype's HTML to
                // instead be a number based on how many items we have
                var newForm = prototype.replace(/__name__/g, index);

                // increase the index with one for the next item
                self.div.data('index', index + 1);

                // Display the form in the page in an li, before the "Add a tag" link li
                self.div.append($(newForm));

                // add a delete link to the new form
                self.addDeleteLink( $(self.div.children(':last-child')[0]) );

                // not a very nice intergration.. but when creating stuff that has help icons,
                // the popovers will not automatically be instantiated
                //initHelpPopovers();

                return $(newForm);
            };

            /**
             * add Delete icon after input
             * @param Element row
             */
            self.addDeleteLink = function (row) {
                var $removeFormA = $('<a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" tabindex="-1"><i class="entypo-trash"></i></a>');
                $(row).find('select').after($removeFormA);
                row.append($removeFormA);
                $removeFormA.on('click', function(e) {
                    // prevent the link from creating a "#" on the URL
                    e.preventDefault();

                    // remove the li for the tag form
                    row.remove();
                });
            };

            self.construct();
        }

    </script>


    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            new FormCollection('col-servliens');
            new FormCollection('col-ports');
        });
    </script>
```

And I get

```
Variable "ports" does not exist.
```

I really need some help.. Collections are actually my nightmare...
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Let me start with apologies, because my answer in the post you mention was clearly wrong :) At least the example code was incorrect. I wonder if the original poster ever found the right solution.

The error is easy enough to spot. In the Twig you use the variable `ports`, but how should Twig know where it comes from?

```
{% for servLiens in form.servLiens %}
<li>{{ form_row(servLiens) }} </li>
    <ul id="col-ports" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(ports.vars.prototype)|e }}">
        {%for ports in servLiens.ports %}
            <li>{{ form_row(ports) }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Using `{{ form_row(servLiens) }}` will actually already create the collection classes, so the whole `<ul>` inside it is not needed. In fact Symfony is smart enough that you don't even need the first `<ul>`. It will find any child forms (ex. collections) and create all the HTML needed.

So the only thing you need to have in your code is:

```
{{ form_row(form.servLiens) }}
```

If you would look at the HTML generated from that, you will see the data-prototype and the children. It will automatically have an id attribute that you can use.

Problem is the javascript part. You are using a collection within a collection. The javascript FormCollection class (which I wrote) cannot handle this as simply as you've tried it. It will handle the top collection fine, but it will not automatically instantiate collections on load/create/delete. Remember that each servLiens collection has a collection of ports. Therefore already at loading you can't simply load the `col-ports` as you do now, but would need to load each port collection. Then you'd need to instantiate a new FormCollection on the port collection every time you add a servLiens row.

I don't have time to create your code for you, but I hope my explanation helps you to find a solution.

Comment: mmh Ok thanks I'll try even though I'm having trouble with simple collection so collection within a collection... I understood what you explained but writing it... thanks for passing by

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you use symfony 2.6 or older.

I would start by saying you should'nt do

```
"'type' => new PortLienAppliServType()"
```

but pass the form type name. Symfony will instantiate it and it *could* be the problem.

Everything is described in extend here: https://symfony.com/doc/2.6/reference/forms/types/collection.html#basic-usage

Honestly, Collections are not that difficult you just need to understand how it works then Symfony will manage everything for you.

Comment: I'm using Symfony 2.7
The form type name is in the function `getName()` right ? In it, I have `return 'mybundle_lienappliserv'` so I tried `'type' => 'mybundle_lienappliserv'` and It says `could not load type 'mybundle_lienappliserv'`

Comment: The `new PortLienAppliServType` is still accepted in Symfony 2, but in Symfony 3 it would become `'type' => PortLienAppliServType::class` instead. Referencing it by the form name will not work. The best practice in Symfony 3 is to not use getName() anymore, which will result in a default naming that suits most needs. In either case this change will not affect anything concerning your problem. It's just aestetics